# How do I update a URL with current Unix Timestamp?

Tags: web-services, unix-timestamp

I would like to build a small web service that gets a URL as input, such as:
www.example.com/timestamp/

and concatenates the Unix Timestamp to it:
www.example.com/timestamp/15090908240.html

That's my first even attempt to do something like that, so I don't even know if I tag this properly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here but 
if I had to do that, i will probably do something like:

```
get('/timestamp', function() {
    Redirect( 'http://example.com/timestamp'.time() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only dealing with strings, you can just concatenate your strings together.

```
url = url + timestamp + ".html";
```

make sure to parse your timestamp as string from long, I'm assuming here that the timestamp you are using is UNIX time, aka Epoch time.